# What's a convenience function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the timeit module there is the code below - what's a convenience function? I googled it and couldn't find a good answer:

```
def timeit(stmt="pass", setup="pass", timer=default_timer,
           number=default_number, globals=None):
    """Convenience function to create Timer object and call timeit method."""
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
```

Comment: A function defined for convenience.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: don't be so dismissive, there's more to it. As GreenCloakGuy's answer mentions, they help prevent litter your namespace with throwaway objects and temporaries. Which is especially important given Python's slightly non-standard scoping rules.

Answer (score 7):

It's a function that exists so you don't have to bother instantiating and keeping track of an object yourself. For example, in the `timeit` module, the only thing that can actually perform the functionality you want is the `Timer` object - but you as the programmer don't want to care about the lifecycle of that Timer, or bring it into your namespace. Hence, this `timeit.timeit()` function creates a `Timer` object relatively anonymously and calls `timeit()` on it, without you needing to keep track of that `Timer` object. *It'll just do what you want it to and you don't have to worry about the details* - convenience.

There are numerous other functions like this, that are essentially wrappers for instantiating a class and running a method - another example is `subprocess.run()`, which creates a `Popen` object that, again, the programmer doesn't have to keep track of.

See also [the Wikipedia definition of a convenience function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_function).

Comment: how are such functions realized? that is the cared object is kept in track during runtime? could you give example or link to example?

Comment: @jojo_Aero_smith_the_dummy the OP's question gives an example of a convenience function that works like this. Amusingly, the timer keeps _itself_ in memory even if it's no longer in any active scope, because it's expected to interact with the rest of the program once it goes off. In much the same way that, say, Singleton classes keep themselves in memory despite not actively being referenced by anything.

Answer (score 1):

## Consider this:

```
animal_list = ["Bear", "Snake", "Snail"]
class_list = ["Mammal", "Reptile", "Gastropod"]

# Scenario 1
for i in range(len(animal_list)):
    animal = animal_list[i]
    class_ = class_list[i]
    print(f"A {animal} is a {class_}.")

# zip() - a convenience function - Scenario 2
for animal, class_ in zip(animal_list, class_list):
    print(f"A {animal} is a {class_}.")
```

## Produced the same result:

```
A Bear is a Mammal.
A Snake is a Reptile.
A Snail is a Gastropod.
```

Scenario 1: Without the use of a convenience function

- Clutter code; much difficult to read and understand

Scenario 2: With the use of a convenience function

- Cleaner code and much more *convenient*